# Failed to install a custom python module in pythonanywhere

Tags: python, module, installation, pythonanywhere

So I'm new in pythoneverywhere. I was trying to install a custom python module ([dryscrape](https://github.com/niklasb/dryscrape)) for myself but failed. I did not load it into my file system in pythonanywhere. I use python 2.6
So, what's wrong/missing:

```
 ~ $ pip2.6 install --igorsavinkin dryscrape                                   

Usage:   
  pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
  pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
  pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
  pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
  pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...

no such option: --igorsavinkin
~ $ pip2.6 install dryscrape                                                  
Collecting dryscrape
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement dryscrape
  No distributions at all found for dryscrape
```

tryed to include it from github but failed too

```
~ $ pip2.6 install https://github.com/niklasb/dryscrape
Collecting https://github.com/niklasb/dryscrape
  Downloading https://github.com/niklasb/dryscrape
     | 45kB 14.1MB/s
  Cannot unpack file /tmp/pip-53bAWe-unpack/dryscrape (downloaded from /tmp/pip-4KCbIJ-build, 
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8); cannot detect archive format
  Cannot determine archive format of /tmp/pip-4KCbIJ-build
```

Should i download it to file system first?

Comment: Are you trying to install `dryscrape`?

Comment: I think you're a bit confused with the first command.  It should be `pip2.6 install --user dryscrape`.  The `--user` is to be taken literally, not replaced with your actual username.  Anyway, the point about Python 2.7 made in itzmeontv's response is possibly more important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note that dryscrape is written for Python 2.7+** I successfully installed `dryscrape` in `pythonanywhere`:

```
git clone https://github.com/niklasb/dryscrape.git dryscrape
cd dryscrape
#try this in virtualenv

virtualenv env
source env/bin/activate

pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Then install dryscrape

```
python setup.py install
```

From doc http://dryscrape.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html

Comment: @itmeontv, thank you, but in pythonanywhere i am not clear of how to upgrade to 2.7?

Comment: Are trying this in `console` in `pythonanywhere`

Comment: i got 2.7.6 default in bash. But in console we can select version.